# background image + media queries

Tags: css, background, media-queries

I am struggling with media queries right now. My project is stored here: http://colorfill.pl/clients/ratuszowa

as you see on the top there is a huge photo as one of the main top elements. What I would like to achieve is to have always image for 100%. I made a really dummy-method. Ive sliced the photo into several files (each has its own width). But the problem appear when i want to put it into media queries..

I prepared photos for such resolutions (showing right now only width of screen):
768
1024
1280
1360
1440
1600
1920
2048
2560
Just like I mention - each resolution will have own  img. I've tried with sth like that:
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) { }
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) { }
but the image display still the same - the smallest. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Place your css here. The order of queries matter.

Comment: @devundef: here u go:

http://justpaste.it/17kc

Comment: the rules are ok. You're using min-width and placing the rules from the smallest to largest screens. It don't works even on desktop if you resize the window?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I have less time to test such a thing because it has to be tested only then I can come to any conclusion, but try looking at these links in case you are using those images as a full page background and your css skills are falling short of what might be required.

**1**. **http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/**

**2**. **http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/**

Comment: Thanks Nina - of course i know those url's but in my case i need to do it via background: /css. Without <img src="#"> tag.